# Kotlin Enum that is simultaneously a String

Tags: kotlin, enums

I'd like to define a set of constants strings as a convenient enumeration for peace of mind on compile time. It feels obvious (with my Python background at least) that simple enumerations could be used as string instances.

```kotlin
// Fine for overall use
enum class Things{ FIRST, SECOND, THIRD }
containsThings[Things.FIRST]

// If a String is expected, this works but has extra stuff
enum class Things(val v: String){
    FIRST("FIRST"), SECOND("SECOND"), THIRD("THIRD")
}
// I want to get rid of ".v"
containsThings[Things.FIRST.v]

// Naïve desired syntax
enum class Things: String { FIRST, SECOND, THIRD }
containsThings[Things.FIRST]
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: As a general point, it's worth noting that patterns and idioms that work well in one language don't necessary translate well to another — especially between dynamic/weakly-typed and static/strongly-typed ones. Learning a new language is as much about learning new idioms, approaches, and mental pictures as it is about syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that to work, your enum class would have to be a subclass of `String`. That's doubly impossible, first because you can't specify a superclass for an enum class, and second because `String` is not `open` and cannot be subclassed.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for the answer. Is there any trickery that can be performed to make this better? Delegated properties come to my mind, but I'm not really familiar enough with those. The language has cool features so this seems like an oversight.

Comment: @Felix: Even with delegated properties, you'd still need to access the property. They're basically Kotlin's version of Python's `@property`.

Comment: (Kotlin was deliberately designed to avoid implicit conversions. The lack of an easy way to implicitly convert enums to strings is probably not an oversight.)

Comment: Damn, yeah doesn't have to be implicit. Explicit is always better ;) but I'll stick to the solution above then. Thanks again.

Comment: @Felix You _could_ define an `operator fun <V> Map<String, V>.get(key: Things): V? = this[key.name]` extension function or something similar. Not sure it's worth it though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want an "enum string" to solve some kind of problem; while, as user2357112 pointed out, Kotlin does not have enum strings, there may be other ways to solve your original problem.

1. Choosing to go for maximum maintainability: having a String as key in a map may not be a good idea if you only want there to be a few allowed keys. Strings can be a bit too flexible for maintainability (you can google 'Stringly typed variables' for a discussion). Code using the enum as key would then look like:

```
enum class Things { FIRST, SECOND, THIRD }
val containsThings = mapOf(Things.FIRST to 1, Things.SECOND to 2, Things.THIRD to 3)
containsThings[Things.FIRST]
// if you add import Things.* to the start of the file, you 
// can even make that val containsThings = mapOf(FIRST to 1, SECOND to 2,...)
```

2. If you want the map to be flexible and have Strings as keys, but there are a few special predefined values, you can use an object:

```
object Things {
    const val FIRST = "FIRST"
    const val SECOND = "SECOND"
    const val THIRD = "THIRD"
}

val containsThings = mapOf(Things.FIRST to 1, Things.SECOND to 2, Things.THIRD to 3)
containsThings[Things.FIRST]
```

There may be other ways, even ways that combine the 'enumerability' of enums and the flexibility of String keys, but I think that in many cases either of above approaches would work fine and be concise enough for usage.

Comment: Unfortunately I am forced to deal with strings due to some APIs. But the second approach is interesting. Does it have drawbacks compared to enumerations?

Comment: Thank you for providing the context that you need strings due to APIs. Enumerations have the main advantage that you have a "limited class" so you cannot use 'wrong values' (if a vet would save animals as strings, he/she might mistype "dog" as "doh" and not find it again when looking for all dogs). The "object way" of doing things has the disadvantages that you don't have the full toolset an enum provides (you can easily get all the values of an enum into an array, you can get the ordinal number of an enum, enums have ranges...) But if you don't need those features, an object works fine.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not possible for an enum value to *be* a string, it's easy to convert between Strings and enum values.

One way to get rid of the "extra stuff" like the `v` property is to take advantage of the built-in `Enum.name` property and `Enum.valueOf(String)` method. See [Working with enum constants](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants).

For example:

```
enum class Thing { FIRST, SECOND, THIRD }

// get the name of an enum value
val thingName : String = Thing.FIRST.name // "FIRST"

// get enum value by name
val thing : Thing = Thing.valueOf("FIRST")
```

Incidentally, at the risk of venturing into opinion territory, the prevailing naming convention is to use singular (`Thing`) instead of plural (`Things`) when naming enum classes in Kotlin.

Comment: True, using the name at least avoids having to write it twice when defining the enum! And I'll agree with you on the naming as well, but that's beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

Not an `enum` but perhaps closer to what you are looking for: sealed class with `data objects` ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#data-objects), since [Kotlin 1.9.0](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew19.html#stable-data-objects-for-symmetry-with-data-classes)) :

```kotlin
sealed class Thing {
    companion object {
        private fun of(str: String): Thing = when (str.uppercase()) {
            "FIRST", "1ST" -> FIRST
            "SECOND" -> SECOND
            "THIRD" -> THIRD
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("not a Thing: '$str'")
        }
        // sugar
        operator fun invoke(str: String): Thing = of(str)
        operator fun invoke(vararg strings: String): List<Thing> = strings.map { str -> of(str) }
    }

    data object FIRST : Thing()
    data object SECOND : Thing()
    data object THIRD : Thing()
}


fun main() {
    println(Thing.SECOND) // SECOND
    //
    println(Thing("first"))                  // FIRST
    println(Thing("first", "second", "1st")) //  [FIRST, SECOND, FIRST]
    println(Thing("first", "last"))          // ...IllegalArgumentException... not a Thing: 'last'
}
```